# SQL Subquery with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this kind of database with columns: `id, date, time, desc, user_id`

```
id|date      |time    |desc|user_id
1 |12-11-1990|09:00:00|In  |1
2 |12-11-1990|18:00:00|Out |1
3 |12-11-1990|09:00:00|In  |2
4 |12-11-1990|18:00:00|Out |2
5 |13-11-1990|10:00:00|In  |1
6 |13-11-1990|17:00:00|Out |1
```

And I want to know, how to make the table looks like it like this when using query

```
date      |in      |out     |user_id
12-11-1990|09:00:00|18:00:00|1
12-11-1990|09:00:00|18:00:00|2
13-11-1990|10:00:00|17:00:00|1
```

Tried to subquery it, but get an error because it returns multiple rows.

```
SELECT date, (
    SELECT time 
    FROM absensi
    WHERE desc="In"
) AS CHECK_IN, (
    SELECT time 
    FROM absensi
    WHERE desc="Out"
) AS CHECK_OUT
FROM absensi GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Shown DATE values are not legal in MySQL, `YYYY-MM-DD` must be used.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: It's still unclear what output you want. Edit your question and show your expected output.

Comment: thank you for your advice, already edit the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want one row per user per day.  This might be as simple as:

```
select date, user_id, min(time), max(time)
from t
group by date, user_id;
```

This assumes that the `in` is always before the `out`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I already edit the expected result for the question. What I want is show the check in and checkout time of each existing user everyday.

Comment: @AnandaPramono . . . I think this does what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT dates.`date`, t1.`time` `In`, t2.`time` `Out`
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT `date`
       FROM absensi ) dates
LEFT JOIN absensi t1 USING (`date`)
LEFT JOIN absensi t2 USING (`date`)
WHERE t1.desc = 'In'
  AND t2.desc = 'Out'
```

The query assumes that there is no 2 or more rows with the same `(date, desc)` combination.

Comment: Thank you for your response, But if there are more user, there will be duplicate rows with the same `date` and `desc`